# rel2abs in perl, to resolve ..'s in the file paths

Tags: perl

```
  my $dep_file="/local/mnt/LINUX/platform/gnss/v02.d"; #is my dep file
  open my $FH, $dep_file or die "Could not open $dep_file: $!";
  my $cwd = getcwd();
  while( my $dep = <$FH>)  {
      if ($dep =~ /$cwd/) { #interested only in lines starting with $cwd
         $dep =~ s/^\s*//; #remove whitespaces in the beginning.
         $dep =~ s/\s+\\\s*$//; # remove white space followed by \ at the end.
         print File::Spec->rel2abs( $dep ) ; #trying to print full path of file without a ".." in it.
         #print $dep;
         print "\n";
         }
      last if $dep =~ /^$/; # don't want to read any line after an empty line.
   }
  close $FH;
```

but the result is not as expected:

```
/local/mnt/LINUX/platform/../source/gnss/api/src/v02.c
/local/mnt/LINUX/project/../source/gnss/api/../../hexagon-infra/q6-00/include/internal.h
```

I want lines to be printed without ".." after resolving ..'s in it, something like below

```
/local/mnt/LINUX/source/gnss/api/src/v02.c
/local/mnt/LINUX/source/hexagon-infra/q6-00/include/internal.h
```

can you please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: add this in your loop `$dep =~ s|/[^/]+/\.\./|/|g while $dep =~ m|/../|;`

Answer (score 3):

```
/local/mnt/LINUX/platform/../source/gnss/api/src/v02.c
```

does not necessarily refer to

```
/local/mnt/LINUX/source/gnss/api/src/v02.c
```

because

```
/local/mnt/LINUX/platform
```

could be a symlink. As such, `x/..` cannot be collapsed safely without a file system check. File::Spec doesn't perform any file system checks, but Cwd does.

```
use Cwd qw( abs_path );

print abs_path( $dep );
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the function `realpath()` from the `Cwd` module:

```
use Cwd qw<realpath>;
...
print File::Spec->rel2abs( realpath($dep) ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print Cwd::realpath( $dep ) ;
```

works.